# ImageMagick, paperclip, macOs Sierra

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, macos-sierra

I'm totally desperate. I've been trying to install ImageMagick form two days and I still have problems with Paperclip gem i Rails.
I'm using macOS Sierra and I've installed the ImageMagick through MacPorts

```
sudo port install ImageMagick
```

I've checked the install directory:

```
which identify
```

and it returned opt/local/bin/identify

I've changed the development.rb using:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin"
```

when I've typed in the console

```
port info ImageMagick
```

I have this

```
ImageMagick @6.9.5-10 (graphics, devel)
Variants:             graphviz, lqr, pango, rsvg, universal, wmf, 
[+]x11

Description:          ImageMagick is a robust collection of tools and 
libraries
                  to create, edit and compose bitmap images in a wide
                  variety of formats. You can crop, resize, rotate, sharpen,
                  color reduce or add effects or text or straight or curved
                  lines to an image or image sequence and save your
                  completed work in the same or differing image format. You
                  can even create images from scratch. Image processing
                  operations are available from the command line as well as
                  through C, Ch, C++, Java, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby and
                  Tcl/Tk programming interfaces. Over 90 image formats are
                  supported, including GIF, JPEG, JPEG 2000, PNG, PDF,
                  PhotoCD and TIFF.
Homepage:             http://www.imagemagick.org/

Extract Dependencies: xz
Build Dependencies:   autoconf, automake, libtool
Library Dependencies: bzip2, djvulibre, xz, jbigkit, jpeg, lcms2,
libpng, tiff,
                  webp, zlib, fftw-3, freetype, fontconfig,   
ghostscript,
                  libiconv, libtool, openjpeg, openexr, expat, libxml2,
                  pkgconfig, xorg-libX11, xorg-libXext, xorg-libXt
Runtime Dependencies: urw-fonts
Platforms:            darwin
License:              Apache-2
Maintainers:          ryandesign@macports.org
```

When I create a "recipe" tehre is an error:

**Paperclip::Error in RecipesController#create
There was an error processing the thumbnail for 215f68293f2d16f1f79bd2e366a45a9620160928-61978-d794or**

My controller looks like this:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def index
    @recipe = Recipe.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
end

def show
end

def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save
        redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Succesfully created new recipe'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
        redirect_to @recipe
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @recipe.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Succesfully deleted"
end

private

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :description, :image)
end

def find_recipe
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

Model:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x400#>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

and the form:

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
- if @recipe.errors.any?
    #errors
        %p
            = @recipe.errors.count
            Prevented this recipe froms saving
        %ul
            - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                %li= msg
.panel-body
    = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
    = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
    = f.input :image, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

When I create the recipe without choosing the image it works fine, but when I choose one I have an error.

I don't know where's the problem. Shall I update the MagickInfo or ...?

Answer (score 0):

It might be help to uninstall xz

```
brew uninstall xz
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows how stupid I am. The problem was with adBlock running in Chrome. It also blocked images in Rails.